# Radio Button Space issue in Android

Tags: android, radio-button, spacing

I am developing quiz on android it is working fine but my layout formatting is giving space issues while using radio buttons. Below is my layout xml and the screen shot. Can any body suggest on this its a padding issue.

[image]

[image]

```
    <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/group1">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:id="@+id/question" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" android:textSize="24sp"
            />
         <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="20sp" android:textColor="@color/black" android:layout_marginLeft="225dp" 
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            />

        <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black" android:layout_marginLeft="225dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="@color/black" android:layout_marginLeft="225dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer4" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="@color/black" android:layout_marginLeft="225dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

         <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer5" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black" android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="225dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" android:visibility="gone"/>

        <RadioButton android:checked="false" android:id="@+id/answer6" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" android:layout_marginLeft="225dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" android:visibility="gone"/>  

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but try putting TextView outside of RadioGroup.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is coming from your oversized margins. You can try modifying the properties of your RadioGroup like this :

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content" // instead of fill_parent
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" // centers the group inside its parent
```

and replace the margins in your radio elements (same for the TextView) :

```
android:layout_marginLeft="something" //creating your issue
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/side_margins" // proposed solution
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/side_margins" // proposed solution
```

You can define side margins according to the design guidelines in your res/values/dimens.xml. I'd start with 8dp, but have a read here for the reference : http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html